# Реализация getSharedPreferences в методе OnPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, android-preferences

Имеется совершенно стандартный метод обратного вызова `OnPreferenceChangeListener`, который создаётся автоматически при добавлении Settings Activity в Android Studio. Но если внутри метода добавить сохранение настройки через `getSharedPreferences`, то эта самая строка подчёркивается красным и выдаёт ошибку `Non-static method getSharedPreferences cannot be referenced from a static context`. Если у `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` убрать `static`, ошибка в данном месте пропадает, но зато по всему коду другая ошибка.
В общем прошу помочь как в методе `OnPreferenceChangeListener` сделать простое сохранение через `getSharedPreferences`?

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        ...
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new ViewPreference()).commit();
        }

    public static class ViewPreference extends PreferenceFragment
        {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
            summaryValue(findPreference("preference"));
            }
        }

    private static void summaryValue(Preference preference)
        {
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(inSummaryValue);
        inSummaryValue.onPreferenceChange(
            preference,
            PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                .getStringSet(preference.getKey(), null));
        }

    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener inSummaryValue = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener()
        {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue)
            {
            SharedPreferences sPref = getSharedPreferences("file_preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor sPrefEdit = sPref.edit();
            sPrefEdit.putInt("status", 1);
            sPrefEdit.apply();
            return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Из каких соображений метод `summaryValue(...)` и поле `inSummaryValue` объявлены как `static`?

Comment: @post_zeew, даже не знаю. Это готовый код, который добавил Android Studio при добавлении Settings Activity, просто я кое-что чуток переименовал и модифицировал, но фактически ничего не трогал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема у вас в непонимании сути статических членов класса. В данном случае `inSummaryValue` - это статический внутренний класс. Он не имеет доступа к состоянию (нестатическим полям) и методам внешнего класса. По этому вы и не можете вызвать в нём метод `getSharedPreferences` класса активити.

Но у вас есть `Preference` как аргумент метода `onPreferenceChange` и из него вы можете `SharedPreferences` получить согласно [доке](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getSharedPreferences()):

```
SharedPreferences sPref = preference.getSharedPreferences();
```

Comment: Если записать именно так `SharedPreferences sPref = preference.getSharedPreferences()`, то ошибка пропадает, но в таком случае обращение идёт к стандартным настройкам имя которых равно имени пакета. У меня же немного иная ситуация, мне нужно обратиться настройкам с именем, которое я им задал. В этом случае нужно записать `SharedPreferences sPref = preference.getSharedPreferences("file_preference", MODE_PRIVATE)`, но в этом случае ошибка указывает на эту часть `("file_preference", MODE_PRIVATE)`. Текст ошибки `getSharedPreferences() in Preference cannot be applied to (java.lang.String, int)`

Comment: @Gamlet, в таком случае перенесите `inSummaryValue ` и `summaryValue` в класс `ViewPreference` и сделайте их не статическими. Тогда должен быть доступ к нужному вам методу.

Comment: Перенёс и сделал. Теперь ругается на то, что `ViewPreference` статичный. Если и его сделать не статичным, то ругается, что он должен быть статичным.

Comment: @Gamlet, где и как ругается на статичность?

Comment: Если `ViewPreference` статичный, то ругается `getSharedPreferences` с тем же самым текстом ошибки что указана в топике. Если же `ViewPreference` сделать не статичным,  то подчёркивается само название `ViewPreference` и в ошибке указывается на необходимость статичности из-за расширения фрагмента `This fragment inner class should be static`

Comment: @Gamlet, ага... Тогда попробуйте заменить `getSharedPreferences` на `getActivity().getSharedPreferences()`, оставив фрагмент статическим.

Comment: О, даа ))  Теперь всё работает!! Спасибо большое. В который раз выручаете ))